# Problem in ArrayAdapter for Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, android-arrayadapter

I want to show custom list view. I have implemented like : [Ch. 4: ListActivity Extended](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity) in Android ListView and ListActivity - Tutorial 
Is there any way to show list without passing whole String[] name. I want to pass only few names (5 to 6 names) which are on the screen and pass other names dynamically when scrolling the screen ?

Is it must to give a data set to the ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: Are the names coming from a database query?

Comment: No. But if yes then is it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Try an [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) for dynamically add item when scrolling the screen